# How can I remove require from TS output file for properties defined with declare?

Tags: typescript

I have the file with declarations for the external JS library:
events.ts

```
export declare EVENT_PLAYER_COMMAND_TEXT: string
... more other events
```

I import this event in my index.js:

```
import { EVENT_PLAYER_COMMAND_TEXT } from '../types/default/events';
on(EVENT_PLAYER_COMMAND_TEXT, () => {})
```

In output JS file I get:

```
var event_1 = require('../types/default/events')
on(event_1.EVENT_PLAYER_COMMAND_TEXT, () => {})
```

BUT, the library expects that I will use EVENT_PLAYER_COMMAND_TEXT without event_1 or any other variable. So the output result in JS must be:

```
on(EVENT_PLAYER_COMMAND_TEXT, () => {})
```

How could I achieve that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can preserve import/export statements with [the `module` setting in tsconfig.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#module)

Any value that is `es20XX` or `esnext` should preserve import export statements.

But this setting is for making sure that the import/export syntax works in your target environment. So depending on where you run this code, this change may break imports entirely.

That said, if `import` getting transpiled to `require` works in your target environment at all, then the way typescript transpiled that should work just fine. It should functionally identical.